# Is there a way to add list elements that is equal to a given number with higher elements

Tags: python

I am trying to add list elements that are closest or equal to 15

I am assuming 1st element from the list as total.
It should add in total with 3rd element from top to bottom.
If total > 15 then it should not add in total and go for the next loop.

I am trying the below code, could you suggest here what I am doing wrong -

```
list1 = [
                [5.0, 1.3, 6.6, 5.076923076923077],
                [9.0, 1.5, 7.0, 4.666666666666667],
                [4.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0],
                [3.0, 2.0, 5.5, 2.75],
                [7.0, 1.6, 3.5, 2.1875],
                [2.0, 1.7, 3.5, 2.058823529411765],
                [1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 2.0],
                [6.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0],
                [8.0, 2.5, 5.0, 2.0],
                [10.0, 1.8, 1.0, 0.5555555555555556]
            ]

income = 15
total = 0

for i in list1:
    if not (total + i[1] > 15):
        total += i[1]
    
print(total)
```

the output should be 14.9

Comment: How do you get 14.9?

Comment: when we iterate list1 - 
total = total + i[1]
it should near to 15

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. What numbers are you adding in your example to get 14.9?

Comment: No it isn't. "It should add in total with 3rd element from top to bottom." The third elements are 6.6,7.0,4.0, etc. Doesn't sum to 14.9 however I try. Can't you specify which numbers you used to get your output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a break.
You have to check that adding the current
number in your loop will not result in the
total sum being more than 15.

```
income = 15
total = 0

for i in list1:
    if not (total + i[1] > income):
      total += i[1]
```

But this code will not always work. because number might come in different orders there might be an order were it adds up to exactly 15 but that's a bit more complicated.